# How to equal or not equal two json objects with respect to json path using java

Tags: java, json, geojson

Want to compare two json object, whether both are same in structure with the help of json path.I am not considering values but only structure.Thank you in advance for any help
        For example below two json file json-1 and json-2, both are same in structure, but you can see values are different.

json-1

```
{
  "squadName": "Super hero squad",
  "homeTown": "Metro City",
  "formed": 2016,
  "secretBase": "Super tower",
  "active": true,
  "members": [
    {
      "name": "man1",
      "age": 50,
      "secretIdentity": "Dan",
      "powers": [
        "Radiation resistance",
        "Turning tiny",
        "Radiation blast"
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Madame Uppercut",
      "age": 39,
      "secretIdentity": "Jane Wilson",
      "powers": [
        "Million tonne punch",
        "Damage resistance",
        "Superhuman reflexes"
      ]
    }    
  ]
}
```

json-2

```
{
  "squadName": "Super hero1",
  "homeTown": "Metro City",
  "formed": 2016,
  "secretBase": "Super tower",
  "active": true,
  "members": [
    {
      "name": "Man2",
      "age": 33,
      "secretIdentity": "Jukes",
      "powers": [
        "Radiation resistance",
        "Turning tiny",
        "Radiation blast"
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Madame Uppercut1111",
      "age": 30,
      "secretIdentity": "ran",
      "powers": [
        "Million tonne punch",
        "Damage resistance",
        "Superhuman reflexes"
      ]
    }    
  ]
}
```

below two json are of different structure:

```
{
  "squadName": "Super hero1",
  "homeTown": "Metro City",
  "formed": 2016,
  "secretBase": "Super tower",
  "active": true,
  "members": [
    {
      "name": "Man2",
      "age": 33,
      "secretIdentity": "Jukes",
      "powers": [
        "Radiation resistance",
        "Turning tiny",
        "Radiation blast"
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Madame Uppercut1111",
      "age": 30,
      "secretIdentity": "ran",
      "powers": [
        "Million tonne punch",
        "Damage resistance",
        "Superhuman reflexes"
      ]
    }    
  ]
}

and 


{
  "Name": "Super hero1",
  "Town": "Metro City",
  "year": 2016,
  "base": "Super tower",
  "IsActive": true,
  "associates": [
    {
      "name1": "Man2",
      "age1": 33,
      "secretIdentity1": "Jukes",
      "powers1": [
        "Radiation resistance",
        "Turning tiny",
        "Radiation blast"
      ]
    },
    {
      "name1": "Madame Uppercut1111",
      "age1": 30,
      "secretIdentity1": "ran",
      "powers1": [
        "Million tonne punch",
        "Damage resistance",
        "Superhuman reflexes"
      ]
    }    
  ]
```

I have written code as mentioned below.Getting keys from both json objects
and comparing both.Wanted to verify whether my logic is correct.

```
    List<String>list4 =printJsonObject(obj);
    List<String>list5 =printJsonObject(obj1);

    if(list5.containsAll(list4)){
        boolean res=true;
          System.out.println("res"+res);

    }




  public static List printJsonObject(JSONObject jsonObj) throws 
     JSONException {
            Iterator keys = jsonObj.keys();
             List<String> jsonKeys=new ArrayList<String>();

           while(keys.hasNext()){

                //based on you key types
                Object keyObj = (String)keys.next();
                Object keyvalue = jsonObj.get(keyObj.toString());
                jsonKeys.add(keyObj.toString());  
                //for nested objects iteration if required

                if (keyvalue instanceof JSONObject)
                    printJsonObject((JSONObject)keyvalue);
            }

           return jsonKeys;
   }
```

Comment: So what did you try so far?

Comment: @rand What do you mean by structure? Could you give some example? Also you can post any code that you tried.

Comment: @YugSingh I have updated my post.Please have a look and suggest if you have any idea.

Comment: @rand could you also give an example of two json objects not equal structurally?

Comment: @YugSingh - Updated the the post with two json having different structure

Answer (score 1):

If the structure is consistent, one thing you can do is try to convert those JSON objects by mapping them to a class. If it finds any other key that is not present, it will raise an exception, and by catching it, you know they have different structure. This is enabled by default and can be disabled with the annotation `@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)` and play around with that.

One good way to do this is by adding Jackson library [this is a good link tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-object-mapper-tutorial) and doing the following:

```
class Foo {
    @JsonProperty("squadName") String name;
    // (other props...) 
}
```

Comment: It will not work it values are different. The author says `...only structure`.

Comment: Sounds great! Thanks!